# Using multiple parameters with arguments with Savon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rubygems, savon

I'm not getting the expected results with the `savon gem` passing multiple parameters and giving them attributes.

Input:

```
message: {
        parameterId: 'timePeriod',       
        :query => [[:parameter=>{:@KeyId=>'geo', :@Value=>'528'}],
                  [:parameter=>{:@KeyId=>'timeType', :@Value=>'5'}]]     
      }
```

Actual output:

```
 <env:Body>
    <tns:DiscoverParameterValues>
      <tns:parameterId>timePeriod</tns:parameterId>
      <tns:query>
        <element>
          <parameter KeyId="geo" Value="528"/>
        </element>
      </tns:query>
      <tns:query>
        <element>
          <parameter KeyId="timeType" Value="5"/>
        </element>
      </tns:query>
    </tns:DiscoverParameterValues>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Expected output:

```
<env:Body>
    <tns:DiscoverParameterValues>
      <tns:parameterId>timePeriod</tns:parameterId>
      <tns:query>
          <parameter KeyId="geo" Value="528"/>
          <parameter KeyId="timeType" Value="5"/>
      </tns:query>
    </tns:DiscoverParameterValues>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make make an array of hashes. Savon will then replicate it for each item in the array.

```
query: {
  parameter: [
    {:@KeyId=>'geo', :@Value=>'528'}, 
    {:@KeyId=>'timeType', :@Value=>'5'}
  ]
}
```

I found this answer here - https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/713 Thanks you glennfu.